# Как выключить черно-белый режим Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Дело именно в Windows. После выхода из системы, все возвращает свой прежний цвет.

В настройках драйвера - ничего. Intel HD Graphics 520.

[image: черно-белая картинка]

Comment: Переустановите драйвера.

Comment: Вероятно поможет эта статья: [How To Turn On Color Filters to Grayscale Your Whole Desktop](https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-10-color-filters)

Comment: параметры/ персонализация / параметры высокой контрастности/  и надо отключить  "применить цветовой фильтр"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> вам в помощь

Answer (score 6):

Посмотрите в **Пуск->Параметры->Специальные возможности** в разделе **Цвет и высокая контрастность**, возможно просто включили фильтр случайно. Если нет, значит вполне вероятно проблема с драйвером

Answer (score 2):

Включить цветовой фильтр: <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Извините, а чем ваше решение отлличается от уже опубликованых?

Comment: @0xdb порядок другой )

Comment: @VladSpirin Тогда надо обязательно указать, каким палцем, какой руки, и главное, какая задержка между нажатием отдельных клавиш в последовательности должна соблюдатся в _мсек._.

Comment: @VladSpirin, здесь есть название _"включить цветовой фильтр"_ - может кому-то пригодиться.

Comment: @0xdb, здесь есть название _"включить цветовой фильтр"_ - может кому-то пригодиться.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно только предполагать... Если оставить, то надо расширить ответ и отредактировать его. Автор даже не зарегистрированный пользователь.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если по поводу моего 2-го комментария, то можно удалить, вчера же 1-е апреля было.